# Change mouse cursor to hand pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Is there a way to change the mouse cursor from an arrow to a hand in pygame? I've made a button in pygame, and have it changing colors when the mouse hovers over it, but I would like the cursor to change to a hand. He're what I have so far:

```
class Button(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, width, height, centerx, centery, text):
        """Initialize the button"""
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill(COLORS["light-blue"])

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = centerx
        self.rect.centery = centery

        self.font = pygame.font.Font('clear-sans.medium.ttf', self.rect.height-4)
        self.text = self.font.render(text, True, COLORS["black"])
        self.text_rect = self.text.get_rect()

        self.clicked = False

    def update(self):
        """Update the button"""
        self.text_rect.center = self.rect.center

    def draw(self, screen):
        """Draw the button on the screen"""
        clicked = False

        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.image.fill(COLORS["blue"])
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked is False:
                self.clicked = True
        else:
            self.image.fill(COLORS["light-blue"])

        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
            self.clicked = False

        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        screen.blit(self.text, self.text_rect)

        return self.clicked
```

I know how to change the cursor image, but I wondered if there was a built-in way in pygame to change the cursor to a hand without making a new sprite for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `pygame.SYSTEM_CURSOR_HAND` in `pygame.cursors` for this.

[Documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/cursors.html)